# Value cannot be null.Parameter name: modelState

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am getting this weird error in my dotnet core application. Usually I know that if some of the parameters in the model state are not valid then we receive something similar but here its saying modelstate itself is null

```
at API.Controllers.MyController.Put(Guid id, TerminalModel terminalModel) in /src/API.Controllers.MyController.cs:line 1447
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at DistributedCache.Infrastructure.ResponseCaching.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /src/Cache/Infrastructure/ResponseCaching.cs:line 250
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
at Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment) in /src/Middleware/Middlewares/ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 120
ExceptionMessage    
Value cannot be null.Parameter name: modelState
```

Need help in identifying the issue

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Your "modelState"-Object doesn't seem to have a value (it is null). Check where you put a value on that object.